# Is there a stronger weapon than the trolls bludgeon?

Tags: candy-box-2

Im stuck in candy box 2. I need a stronger weapon to complete harder quests. what is the next weapon I can get?

Comment: I forgot to mention my equipment. I have the trolls bludgeon, the octo-crown, the boots of introspection, and pink enchanted gloves.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A full list of weapons can be found here: http://candybox2.gamepedia.com/Weapon

The next weapon you are likely to get is the Monkey Wizard's staff from defeating a monkey wizard and the caves under the mountain. It does less damage but it shoots magic balls at enemies.

Answer (score 0):

I would kill the octopus king and the monkey wizard. then I would enchant the crown so it is a crown with red jaspers. then I would enchant the staff. the two bosses can be found in the cave. also if you don't have two chocolate bars, look at the floor of the cave while exploring, and you can find 2 items (usually you can see arrows pointing which direction to go on the walls) and one gives you extra HP. I forgot what the other one does though. sometimes you can see rocks arranged on the floor. they mark an place on the map. click it and dig to find 3 chocolate bars. also try to beat some sharks in the ocean, they give you extra boosts. the purple one is hard to get though.

Answer (score 0):

the scythe is much better than the troll's bludgeon it cost is 5,000,000 at the forge in the village